# How to create a global composer command?

Tags: command-line, composer-php

I've created a composer command [`locaload`](https://github.com/rudiedirkx/composer-localoader-plugin), but after requiring it globally, it's not recognized anywhere but in the plugin repo itself. So not very useful.

I don't want to add it to every project/library, and can't even, because some are not mine. I want it to be available everywhere, like all of composer's commands are.

Plugin's `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "rdx/composer-localoader-plugin",
    "description": "Composer plugin to load some dependencies locally",
    "type": "composer-plugin",
    "require": {
        "composer-plugin-api": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "rdx\\localoader\\": ""
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "locaload": "rdx\\localoader\\Plugin::localoadCommand"
    },
    "extra": {
        "class": "rdx\\localoader\\Plugin"
    }
}
```

The `"scripts"` defines the command: `composer locaload x y`. When I run it anywhere else (not the plugin's repo itself):

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "locaload" is not defined.
```

When I run it like a script (`composer run-script locaload -- x y`):

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Script "locaload" is not defined in this package
```

It is indeed not defined in THIS package (or when I'm not even IN a package), but it DOES exist in the global `composer.json` and `composer.lock`.

How do I make this command globally recognized, so I can use it in any project, or even from any non-project location?

The global install works:

```
rudie@home:~$ composer global require rdx/composer-localoader-plugin:dev-master
Changed current directory to /home/rudie/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing rdx/composer-localoader-plugin (dev-master d4f5e85)
    Cloning d4f5e8547a4e23c2febc2ed845e76774ea63e61a

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

and removing it works as well, but doesn't change anything.

When I check the command list globally (`composer list | grep locaload`), it's empty. When I check it inside the plugin repo itself:

```
locaload        Run the locaload script as defined in composer.json.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts are only available when defined in the root package, so you would have to add this to the package you want to use it in:

```
"scripts": {
    "locaload": "rdx\\localoader\\Plugin::localoadCommand"
},
```

But I get that it's not very practical, and one alternative way I guess would be to add a `"bin": "locaload"` or something to your plugin so that when you install it globally it would make it available a binary script you can just run as `locaload ...` and it would act upon the composer.json in the current directory, just not as a composer plugin then. You could still have the plugin part be in place globally to listen to the post-autoload-dump.

I hope this is clear enough.